# matching an entire list with each and every line of file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, performance, dictionary

I had written a piece of code that basically performs find and replace from a list on a text file.

So, it maps the entire list into a dictionary. Then from text file each and every line is processed and is matched with entire list in the dictionary if a match anywhere in the line is found it replaces with corresponding value from the list(dictionary).

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import re

#open file using open file mode
fp1 = open(sys.argv[1]) # Open file on read mode
lines = fp1.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
fp1.close() # Close file


fp2 = open(sys.argv[2]) # Open file on read mode
words = fp2.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
fp2.close() # Close file

word_hash = {}

for word in words:
    #print(word)
    if(word != ""):
        tsl = word.split("\t")
        word_hash[tsl[0]] = tsl[1]

#print(word_hash)
keys = word_hash.keys()
#skeys = sorted(keys, key=lambda x:x.split(" "),reverse=True)
#print(keys)
#print (skeys)

for line in lines:
    if(line != ""):
        for key in keys:
            #my_regex = key + r"\b"
            my_regex = r"([\"\( ])" + key + r"([ ,\.!\"।)])"
            #print(my_regex)
            if((re.search(my_regex, line, re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE))):
                line = re.sub(my_regex, r"\1" + word_hash[key]+r"\2",line,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)
                #print("iam :1",line)
            if((re.search(key + r"$", line, re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE))):
                line = re.sub(key+r"$", word_hash[key],line,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)
                #print("iam :2",line)
            if((re.search(r"^" + key, line, re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE))):
                #print(line)
                line = re.sub(r"^" + key, word_hash[key],line,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)
                #print("iam :",line)
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line)
```

Problem here is when the list size grows execution slows up as all the lines of text file are matched with each and every key in list. So where can I improve the execution of this code.

**List file:**

word1===>replaceword1

word2===>replaceword2

.....

List is tab seperated. Here I used ===> for easy understanding.

**Input file:**

```
hello word1 I am here.

word2. how are you word1?
```

**Expected Output:**

```
hello replaceword1 I am here.

replaceword2. how are you replaceword1?
```

Comment: Can you post sample input files and expected output?

Comment: added sample input and output@Rakesh

Comment: i have some many input files each file is in between 100 to 200 lines from 8K to 20 K

Comment: Reading the entire text into memory, replacing words and saving it back should be the easiest! Check my answer below @Nagaraju

Answer (score 2):

If your word list is small enough, the best speedup you can achieve with the match-and-replace process is to use a single big regexp and use a functionnal `re.sub`

This way you have a single call to the optimised function.

EDIT: In order to preserve order of replacements (this can lead to chain replacing, don't know if intended behavior) we can perform replacement by batches rather than in a single run, where batches order respects file order and each batch is made of disjoint possible string matches.

The code would be as follow

```py
import sys
import re


word_hashes = []

def insert_word(word, replacement, hashes):
    if not hashes:
        return [{word: replacement}]
    for prev_word in hashes[0]:
        if word in prev_word or prev_word in word:
            return [hashes[0]] + insert_word(word, replacement, hashes[1:])
    hashes[0][word] = replacement
    return hashes

with open(sys.argv[2]) as fp2: # Open file on read mode
    words = fp2.readlines()
    for word in [w.strip() for w in words if w.strip()]:
        tsl = word.split("\t")
        word_hashes = insert_word(tsl[0],tsl[1], word_hashes)

#open file using open file mode
lines = []
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp1:
    content = fp1.read()
    for word_hash in word_hashes: 
        my_regex = r"([\"\( ])(" + '|'.join(word_hash.keys()) + r")([ ,\.!\"।)])"
        content = re.sub(my_regex, lambda x: x.group(1) + word_hash[x.group(2)] + x.group(3) ,content,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)

print(content)
```

We obtain chained replacement for the example data. For example, with the following words to replace

```
roses are red==>flowers are blue
are==>is
```

Text to parse

```
roses are red and beautiful
flowers are yellow
```

Output

```
roses is red and beautiful
flowers is yellow
```

Comment: while replacing is the dictionary order not preserved?

Comment: I dont understand, dictionnaries can only have a single entry for a given key, so why would order matter ?

Comment: scenario, list file: roses are red=>flowers are blue, are=>is and input file:roses are red and very beautilful.\nroses are blue. Here roses are red is not getting replaced

Comment: OK I understand. Well i suppose you have to choose between performance and keeping file order in these edge cases... I don't see a quick way to fulfill requirements that would be more efficient and wouldn't need several hours of development.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I checked this code it superb fast but only lacks in order

Comment: You can have best of two worlds with proper developpement. The idea is to build the keys data structure more cleverly. Instead of a dict you must have a list of dicts. As you would insert keys to replace you would check first if there isn't already a key which is a substring in the first dict, and insert in the following dict if otherwise. Then you could replace with each dict using this method, in order. If I have time I will produce a snippet later today.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read the content of the entire file in a string, and just do `string.replace`. For example.

```
def find_replace():

    txt = ''
    #Read text from the file as a string
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
        txt = fp.read()

    dct = {"word1":"replaceword1","word2":"replaceword2"}

    #Find and replace characters
    for k,v in dct.items():
        txt = txt.replace(k,v)

    #Write back the modified string
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(txt)
```

If the input file is:

```
hello word1 I am here.

word2. how are you word1?
```

The output will be:

```
hello replaceword1 I am here.

replaceword2. how are you replaceword1?
```

Comment: won't this replace wherever a match is found like there should be space or any double quotes or it might be starting of the string but not anywhere else.

Comment: No it will find the exact raw string  to replace in the bigger file, and only replace that word! I am reading the full string from file with spaces and newlines here. Give it a try on some examples and see if this breaks!

Comment: it fails on unicode text. text=HTML इमेजेस (Images), list=इमेज=>image. so here the unicode text should not get replaced, but it replaces as HTML imageेस (Images)

Comment: You can modify the dictionary to make the correct replacement for unicode text which is not plain english!

Comment: I think you are not understanding what am saying. For unciode text even if its a part of word it gets replaced, which ideally shoudnot happen

Comment: Could you please update your question with whatever you mentioned in the commend, with a sample input and output that failed for better readability!